# Trim an infinite list of random numbers

Tags: list, haskell, random

I'm trying to trim a list of random numbers so that sum of the numbers in [0,1] in the resulting smaller list accumultates to a value under 1.

This is interesting in a sense that average of these list prefix lengths is `e`, [somehow](https://twitter.com/InertialObservr/status/1183489675274510336).

While getting the length of prefix I encountered a problem - I managed to get the program to work on a determined infinite list, or a slice of random list, but the program hangs on infinite random list. What am I doing wrong?

```
import System.Random

-- Count list items that accumulate to 1.
count :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
count xs = 1 + length xs' 
         where xs'= takeWhile (< 1) $ scanl1 (+) xs

-- Works of infinite list 
a = (return (repeat 0.015)) :: IO [Double]
fa = fmap count a 
--67 

-- Works on trimmed list of randoms
rio = randomRIO (0::Double, 1)         
b = sequence $ take 10 (repeat rio)
fb = fmap count b 
-- fb is usually 2 to 5

-- Hangs on infinite list of randoms
c = sequence (repeat rio)
fc = fmap count c
-- fc hangs... ;(
```

Comment: `sequence (repeat rio)` itself hangs, because it has to complete infinitely many IO actions before yielding any information.  IO is strict.

Comment: @luqui Perhaps more noteworthy is that `take 10 . sequence $ repeat rio` also hangs. Evgeny may well have thought that `sequence $ repeat rio` successfully returns a lazy list, and that only attempting to force it all actually hangs, in the same way that `repeat 0` "hangs" by never finishing evaluation.

Comment: Conceptually, an `IO [Double]` is a *list of instructions*, or an *imperative program*, to compute a `[Double]`. As @luqui says, `sequence (repeat rio)` is an infinite program that repeatedly calls `rio` forever. Laziness will save you from having to compute the infinite list of instructions itself, if it's not needed, but it will *not* save you from having to execute the whole program if you want its result. As the program is infinite, execution never terminates and the result never appears.

Comment: @malloy - indeed I thought once the type signature of the a, b and c is the same, their 'laziness level' should be the same, which was not true, according to all the detailed comments provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an IO action to create an infinite stream of ranged random numbers like so:

```
import System.Random

randomRIOs :: (Random a) => (a, a) -> IO [a]
randomRIOs (a, b) = randomRs (a, b) <$> newStdGen
```

After which, the following works fine with your definition of `count`:

```
main = do
    n <- count <$> randomRIOs (0::Double, 1)
    print n
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't really have an infinite list of random numbers, because randomness is too strict. So, you can't have the call to `sequence` outside of your call to `count`. One obvious thing you could try would be a partial reimplementation of `sequence` inside of `count` itself:

```
count :: (Num a, Ord a, Monad m) => [m a] -> m (Maybe Int)
count = go 0 0
  where go n total [] = pure Nothing
        go n total (x:xs) = do
          num <- x
          let total' = total + num
              n' = succ n
          if total' >= 1
            then pure $ Just n'
            else go n' total' xs
```

I've also amended the result to return a Maybe, because it seems wrong to return 1 for an empty list (as yours did), or return the length of a list even if its elements sum to something less than 1.

Another reasonable change would be to not accept `[m a]`, but just a single `m a`, which can reliably produce a value any number of times. Then we don't have to worry about the input running out, and so no Maybe is needed:

```
count :: (Num a, Ord a, Monad m) => m a -> m Int
count m = go 0 0
  where go n total = do
          num <- m
          let total' = total + num
              n' = succ n
          if total' >= 1
            then pure n'
            else go n' total'
```

Then you can simply call `count $ randomRIO (0::Double, 1)`, and it will produce as many random numbers as are needed.

Comment: What do you mean with "randomness is too strict"?